# Images at Lightswitch v3.0: "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long."

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I got a simple Lightswitch - Silverlight based - web client. Client.csproj and Server.csproj are saying the `LightSwitchVersion` is `v3.0`. It runs on

- Visual Studio 2012 Update 4
- LightSwitch Extensibility Toolkit for VS11
- I have 2 extension, both are selected:

  - LightSwitch Cosmopolitan Shell and Theme
  - Microsoft LightSwitch Extensions

And I got a MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `legend` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `preview` blob,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I declared the `preview` field as an *Image* Type in the data source before I created a screen for the table. But the running application greets me with this

[image: Lightswitch 3.0 has a problem with images]

Using Lightswitch 2.0 everything runs fine. But since I've upgraded to v3.0 this is the only issue spoiling everything :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not run across this myself but interest was piqued. :)

It seems like the OData layer is using the contents of the blob column to ensure data concurrency and that's the URI which is too long. In a native SQL Server table, you can just add a Rowversion column and that will be selected for concurrency purposes - the Lightswitch Intrinsic database does that for you automatically in fact. My understanding is that MySQL doesn't have an equivalent Rowversion type.

The workaround is to create another column on your MySQL table which is incremented by a MySQL trigger on every update, making it a de facto concurrency field. Update the datasource and then edit the .lsml file to add a `<UseForConcurrency />` attribute to that column.

Full discussion is on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/44581489-438d-4844-8194-0b4a0a41e56f/exception-invalid-uri-the-uri-string-is-too-long?forum=lightswitch

Comment: By the way, the switch from RIA to OData as the data layer was between Lightswitch 1.0 and 2.0. Is it possible you upgraded from 1.0 to 3.0?

Comment: I'm not sure but all my `*.csproj` and the `*.lsproj` have the `<LightSwitchVersion>v2.0</LightSwitchVersion>` entry. So I assume I've started with 2.0.

Comment: If you don't want to alter the schema, you may be able to expose the MySQL database as an Odata provider or connect to it using WCF-RIA - both of which I'm guessing would avoid the error but neither of which would be simple. The simplest solution is not to upgrade your project in the first place and keep using the working version.

Comment: This answer contains the key to the solution: `<UseForConcurrency />` But it's far away from a running solution! So I posted my complete implementation for all the MySQL users out there...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to get the **complete** beast running:

### MySQL

Add a column for the concurrency check in the MySQL table:
*(I decided the use `uuid()`. It's the easiest way to get unique values each time I change something!)*

```sql
-- The column itself.
ALTER TABLE images ADD COLUMN rowversion BINARY(16);
-- Setup for all existing rows.
UPDATE images SET rowversion = UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''));
-- Now make it NOT NULL.
ALTER TABLE images MODIFY COLUMN rowversion BINARY(16) NOT NULL;

-- An insert trigger to get a default value for future rows.
CREATE TRIGGER images_before_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON images 
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.rowversion = UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''));
```

### Lightswitch

1. Update Datasource.
2. Save all, close the solution, open the ..\Server\Properties\Service.lsml and just add `<UseForConcurrency />` (and not more) to the rowversion entry (like Phil said). Now it might look like

```xml
  <EntityProperty
    Name="rowversion"
    PropertyType=":Guid">
    <EntityProperty.Attributes>
      <UseForConcurrency />
      <Required />
      <NotSearchable />
    </EntityProperty.Attributes>
  </EntityProperty>
```

But stop, unfortunately that's NOT all! This evil Lightswitch doesn't refetch the rowversion value after saving. So a `BEFORE UPDATE ON images` trigger will never serve our needs. Believe me, you'll end up in the "Data Conflict" hell on each update!!! You have to change the rowversion on the client side:

```cs
public partial class ImageScreen
{
    partial void ImageScreen_Saving(ref bool handled)
    {
        var changes = DataWorkspace.testData.Details.GetChanges();

        foreach (var image in changes
            .ModifiedEntities
            .OfType<image>())
        {
            image.rowversion = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the client nows about the latest rowversion coming from himself. And if another client modifies the same datasets the "Data Conflict" will be proclaimed correcly.